# Working with Langchain I get nlkt errors telling me: Package "tokenizers" not found in index and Packaage "taggers" not found in index

Tags: python, nltk, langchain

I'm trying to load some documents, powerpoints and text to train my custom LLm using Langchain.

When I run it I come to a weird error message where it tells I don't have "tokenizers" and "taggers" packages (folders).

I've read the docs, asked Langchain chatbot, pip install nltk, uninstall, pip install nltk without dependencies, added them with nltk.download(), nltk.download("punkt"), nltk.download("all"),... Did also manually put on the path: nltk.data.path = ['C:\Users\zaesa\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data'] and added all the folders. Added the tokenizers folder and taggers folder from the github repo:https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/tree/gh-pages/packages. Everything. Also asked on the Github repo. Nothing, no success.

Here the code of the file I try to run:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredPowerPointLoader, TextLoader, UnstructuredWordDocumentLoader
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
import os
import openai
import sys
import nltk
nltk.data.path = ['C:\\Users\\zaesa\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data']
nltk.download(
    'punkt', download_dir='C:\\Users\\zaesa\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data')


sys.path.append('../..')

_ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv())  # read local .env file

openai.api_key = os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']

# Replace with the actual folder paths

folder_path_docx = "DB\\ DB VARIADO\\DOCS"
folder_path_txt = "DB\\BLOG-POSTS"
folder_path_pptx_1 = "DB\\PPT DAY JUNIO"
folder_path_pptx_2 = "DB\\DB VARIADO\\PPTX"

# Create a list to store the loaded content
loaded_content = []

# Load and process DOCX files
for file in os.listdir(folder_path_docx):
    if file.endswith(".docx"):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path_docx, file)
        loader = UnstructuredWordDocumentLoader(file_path)
        docx = loader.load()
        loaded_content.extend(docx)

# Load and process TXT files
for file in os.listdir(folder_path_txt):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path_txt, file)
        loader = TextLoader(file_path, encoding='utf-8')
        text = loader.load()
        loaded_content.extend(text)

# Load and process PPTX files from folder 1
for file in os.listdir(folder_path_pptx_1):
    if file.endswith(".pptx"):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path_pptx_1, file)
        loader = UnstructuredPowerPointLoader(file_path)
        slides_1 = loader.load()
        loaded_content.extend(slides_1)

# Load and process PPTX files from folder 2
for file in os.listdir(folder_path_pptx_2):
    if file.endswith(".pptx"):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path_pptx_2, file)
        loader = UnstructuredPowerPointLoader(file_path)
        slides_2 = loader.load()
        loaded_content.extend(slides_2)

# Process the loaded content as needed
# for content in loaded_content:
    # Process the content
    # pass

# print the first 500 characters of the first document
print(loaded_content[0].page_content)
print(nltk.data.path)

# Get the list of installed packages
installed_packages = nltk.downloader.Downloader(
    download_dir='C:\\Users\\zaesa\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data').packages()

# Print the list of installed packages
print(installed_packages)

sent_tokenize("Hello. How are you? I'm well.")
```

When running the file I get:

```
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading taggers: Package 'taggers' not found in
[nltk_data]     index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading taggers: Package 'taggers' not found in
[nltk_data]     index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading taggers: Package 'taggers' not found in
[nltk_data]     index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading taggers: Package 'taggers' not found in
[nltk_data]     index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading tokenizers: Package 'tokenizers' not found
[nltk_data]     in index
[nltk_data] Error loading taggers: Package 'taggers' not found in
[nltk_data]     index

- HERE SOME TEXT -

['C:\\Users\\zaesa\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data']
dict_values([<Package perluniprops>, <Package mwa_ppdb>, <Package punkt>, <Package rslp>, <Package porter_test>, <Package snowball_data>, <Package maxent_ne_chunker>, <Package moses_sample>, <Package bllip_wsj_no_aux>, <Package word2vec_sample>, <Package wmt15_eval>, <Package spanish_grammars>, <Package sample_grammars>, <Package large_grammars>, <Package book_grammars>, <Package basque_grammars>, <Package maxent_treebank_pos_tagger>, <Package averaged_perceptron_tagger>, <Package averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru>, <Package universal_tagset>, <Package vader_lexicon>, <Package lin_thesaurus>, <Package movie_reviews>, <Package problem_reports>, <Package pros_cons>, <Package masc_tagged>, <Package sentence_polarity>, <Package webtext>, <Package nps_chat>, <Package city_database>, <Package europarl_raw>, <Package biocreative_ppi>, <Package verbnet3>, <Package pe08>, <Package pil>, <Package crubadan>, <Package gutenberg>, <Package propbank>, <Package machado>, <Package state_union>, <Package twitter_samples>, <Package semcor>, <Package wordnet31>, <Package extended_omw>, <Package names>, <Package ptb>, <Package nombank.1.0>, <Package floresta>, <Package comtrans>, <Package knbc>, <Package mac_morpho>, <Package swadesh>, <Package rte>, <Package toolbox>, <Package jeita>, <Package product_reviews_1>, <Package omw>, <Package wordnet2022>, <Package sentiwordnet>, <Package product_reviews_2>, <Package abc>, <Package wordnet2021>, <Package udhr2>, <Package senseval>, <Package words>, <Package framenet_v15>, <Package unicode_samples>, <Package kimmo>, <Package framenet_v17>, <Package chat80>, <Package qc>, <Package inaugural>, <Package wordnet>, <Package stopwords>, <Package verbnet>, <Package shakespeare>, <Package ycoe>, <Package ieer>, <Package cess_cat>, <Package switchboard>, <Package comparative_sentences>, <Package subjectivity>, <Package udhr>, <Package pl196x>, <Package paradigms>, <Package gazetteers>, <Package timit>, <Package treebank>, <Package sinica_treebank>, <Package opinion_lexicon>, <Package ppattach>, <Package dependency_treebank>, <Package reuters>, <Package genesis>, <Package cess_esp>, <Package conll2007>, <Package nonbreaking_prefixes>, <Package dolch>, <Package smultron>, <Package alpino>, <Package wordnet_ic>, <Package brown>, <Package bcp47>, <Package panlex_swadesh>, <Package conll2000>, <Package universal_treebanks_v20>, <Package brown_tei>, <Package cmudict>, <Package omw-1.4>, <Package mte_teip5>, <Package indian>, <Package conll2002>, <Package tagsets>])
```

And here is how my folders structure from nltk_data looks like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help will be really appreciated because it is a serious work I have the commitment to achieve.

Will be full available for solving this issue. Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: oh this error trace does not help much, can you try these lines of code and let us know if this works okay for you? `import nltk
nltk.data.path = ['nltk_data']
nltk.download(
    'punkt', download_dir='nltk_data')`

Comment: Nope. Get same errors (this time less lines but the same) plus   Resource averaged_perceptron_tagger not found.
 ` Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:
  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')`  Added this lines too and it still tells me it isn't found. I suspect more and more there is a problem with Langchain not with me or with NLTK. Appreciate anyway any suggestions. People from Langchain doesn't answer, a bit frustrating.

Comment: If nltk download is not working, then it's not langchain issue.

Comment: pls try these suggestions, [NLTK Downloader](https://github.com/delip/PyTorchNLPBook/issues/14) , i cant recreate, so can only suggest, sorry!

Comment: Well. the people from NLTK has looked into it and we followed all the steps they say tit is very weird, they pointed to the unstructured folder from Langchain. I get this errors no matter if I have nltk installed and asked to import or not. So it is quite possible it is a Langchain issue. Will look into the link you have provided

Comment: Ok, well. Have looked into the link you have provided. Already tried. Not working, thanks anyway.

Comment: Just to rule out. Keep one python file and have only the lines I have put in comment , and check if that works? Then can take step by step.

Comment: Others facing same issue: [https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/8419](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/8419). Not sure what it could be...

Comment: will try to look into it, error is coming from unstructured `unstructured/partition/docx.py:230`, I have all the info. thanks

Comment: Appreciate @simpleApp. Will let you know if I find something

Comment: hey, i am still trying to see how critical the error `[nltk_data] Error` is! your `loaded_content` should have the documents stored, can you check if you are getting the `page_content` on them ?

Comment: Solved. They just released a new update from unstructured. It was a bug. I was getting crazy trying to figure out what was wrong... Thanks for your help @simpleApp!! Have a great weekend!

Comment: You are welcome! thanks for chasing it to the closure and contributing to the open-source community. appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

There was a problem with Unstructured from Langchain.

With the new release it works: https://github.com/Unstructured-IO/unstructured/releases/tag/0.8.7

To me it worked just by writting `pip install -U unstructured`